# Setting value of elements from array using function call

Tags: c, arrays, reference, pass-by-reference

I have a certain array on which i need to set values. The values settings should be done using a function call and passing the elements by reference.

This is the deceleration:

```
DataRecord  *pDataRecordArray;
```

Here is the allocation:

```
pDataRecordArray = (DataRecord*)malloc(sizeof(DataRecord*)*iIgnoreBottomRows);
```

This is the setting function:

```
apr_status_t (*get_empty_data_record)(struct W *w,
                                          int                        x, 
                                          struct _DataRecord         **ppDataRecord, <---relevant parameter
                                          size_t                     y,
                                          size_t                     z);
```

And is is how i planned to send the data but an error is given:

```
base_control.get_empty_data_record(w, 0, &pDataRecordArray[0], 0, 0);
```

This of course wont work, but i cant seem to find a way to set the element.

All the other parameters wont matter so hence the XYZ naming.

Thanks

Comment: Please, don't cast the void pointer returned by `malloc`. Most people I know agree that the clearest syntax (and least error prone) for `malloc` is: `type *varName = malloc(10*sizeof *varName);` because you can read it like a sentence: _malloc ten times the memory size of the type "varName" points to_

Comment: An array of pointers to type T has type T**, not T*.

Comment: "All the other parameters wont matter so hence the XYZ naming." You are obscuring so much that your question description is not useful. For example, I reckon that `DataRecord` is typedeffed to `struct _DataRecord *`, but we can't know. What is the purpose of `get_empty_data_record`? Does it set a value in your list of data records? One thing is for sure: It doesn't "get" anything; it returns a status code. Why do you provide the function prototype as function pointer? And why is that pointer part of a struct? There are so many things that are dubious, it's not clear what your real problem is.

Comment: Oh, and if you don't want to show part of your code - the contents of your struct or parameters deemed unneccessary, strip down your code and provide a small, self-contained example that reproduces your error.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling function like this if you are setting element in the array

```
base_control.get_empty_data_record(w, 0, &pDataRecordArray, 0, 0);
```

Comment: In this context, the array name will decay into a pointer to its first element, passing `&pDataRecordArray`, then will pass a pointer to a pointer. (Cf the standard: C11 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

Comment: Thank you Elias Van Ootegem. I have edited the answer